# (VB.net 2012) Repeat user input in a label (simultaneously)

Tags: .net, vb.net, virtual, basic

I want to make a program that repeats(displays) in a label the information that the user has entered into a text box. I want this to happen simultaneously (text in label should appear as the user is writing in the text box).

What is the best way do this?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the TextChanged event of your textbox

See [Control.TextChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Private Sub yourTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles yourTextBox.TextChanged
    'change label text here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the text in the text box to label on the text change event, ie,

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```